# Is there a way to run OpenVZ on a filesystem that doesn't need to fsck?

Tags: filesystems, openvz

I'm running OpenVZ, and occasionally need to power cycle my host. Of course, it has to fsck every time it comes back up (ext4) Is there a way to run OpenVZ on a filesystem that doesn't have to fsck in order to reduce downtime? (AFAIK xfs is not supported yet) Thanks!

Comment: Are you power cycling it without shutting down the OS, letting the filesystem unmount cleanly?  It shouldn't be checking every boot if it's getting clean shutdowns.

Comment: Sometimes machines will just lock up, it's unavoidable.

Comment: So you need a filesystem that writes through? In every other constellation your FS had to be checkd.

Comment: I need a filesystem that doesn't need to fsck, or that can fsck while mounted *and* works with OpenVZ.

Comment: Machines hardly ever lock up.  Locking up is frequently avoidable.

Comment: "Machines hardly ever lock up. Locking up is frequently avoidable." Well...maybe but that is not the scenario I am working with at the moment.

Comment: Also, after a certain number of days a fsck gets forced.

Comment: Honestly, I am still looking for an answer here. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Still wondering about this...

Answer (score 0):

even tough it's not really recomanded if you have several partitions , you could just unmount them and mount again after restart - this will prevent fsck to be used . This could bring some issues after a long time :) .

Alex H